# Saving a list of lists in an object file in Java

Tags: java, file, list, object

I'm currently working on a java project that requires me to make a system for an ATM. I have classes for userList, userNode; each user node contains accountList with accountNode (the accountNode has children classes for types of accounts, such as credit or debit) and the account node contains an operationList with nodes for withdraw, deposit, etc...

I need to be able to read and save to an object file. So I don't lose the data when quitting the program or have to create new users, accounts, etc every time the program runs. However, I'm not sure if I need a new class for creating the object file or what ways there are to do this.

I'd appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: There are many ways to persist objects.

Comment: Why not use a database for this.. This is the type of stuff they where built for..

Comment: If this is a homework-type question, please do add the corresponding tag.

Comment: @barsju I would, but I HAVE to use an object file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Database would be the best and the most real world solution for this but if you do want to write and read from a file, you will need to make your classes implement Serializable.  From there you can look up several tutorials on writing and reading those objects back from a file.

```
public class BankAccount implements Serializable
```

http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/serialization/

If you want to work with a database, go get MySQL or something free.

http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/

Comment: If you go with Object serialization make sure you understand the use of serialVersionUID and the impact that has on deserialization if you need to modify your code..

Comment: This seems like the way to go... I know using a database would be better, but I'm restricted to object files for now. Thank you for the link.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution would be serialization to XML or JSON using for instance jaxb:

http://jaxb.java.net/tutorial/